# Error: User 'postgres' not found in aco_user table when trying to update a table

Tags: postgresql

Logging into PSQL as follows:

```
su postgres
psql -d database_name
```

I can view all tables in the database. However, when I update data in a table (`UPDATE table set column='blue'`) I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  User: 'postgres' not found in aco_user table
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "SELECT aco_message1( 'USER_NOT_FOUND', true, current_user )"
PL/pgSQL function aco_get_current_user_id(boolean) line 8 at PERFORM
PL/pgSQL function aco_get_current_user_id() line 5 at RETURN
PL/pgSQL function aco_user_trigger() line 8 at assignment
```

which prevents me from updating the table.

What is the issue? Postgres is a superuser who should be able to do everything.

EDIT: the aco() functions appear to be custom functions created as part of this database, so I guess they are causing the problem. Can I alter this user defined function to accept Postgres as the user?

Comment: There appears to be a trigger that prevents the change. Speak with the developer of your application.

Answer (score -1):

Simple use SET ROLE user to a user that has permission to alter that database (e.g. the owner).